# Meaning of 'with' in context

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the preposition 'with' in the below sentence? Why has it been used?

> He sat down at the table, with the order that he be served immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It is a strange use of *with*. Perhaps if you gave some context it would be less strange.

Having said that, the meaning is clear: his sitting down was accompanied by his giving the order.